# Transformer surge protection with MOSFETS

Tags: mosfet, protection, over-voltage-protection, diode-clamp

I'm trying to come up with a good solution to protect a 48VAC circuit against power spikes from the transformer when the load is suddenly disconnected.

Since I have a bunch of MOSFETs and Zeners at hand I though about a circuit that shorts the supply above an input voltage higher than the zener threshold. Additionally a fuse could be added that will be blown if the overvoltage condition lasts longer than the transistors can handle the dissipation.

Is there anything wrong with that idea?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0g6Cw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: An overvoltage will probably kill the Zeners as they will shoot through. Better put some resistors in series.

Comment: You would not be the first to want to protect something that doesn't need protection. So show us your **complete** circuit (transformer + what is connected to it) so that we know what this is all about.

Comment: Also as drawn, any voltage bigger than a couple of volts will be clamped by this circuit, so it will not handle 48V

Comment: Thanks @tobalt, I added the series resistors and edited the zeners to a 60V 500mW type in the schematic

Comment: The load is a purely resistive 3 Ohm heating element. What I'm worried about is a SMPS that generates 5VDC from the 24VAC line (LM5017 with rectifier diode + cap at the input)

Comment: Did you simulate this ? I still believe that the MOSFET will conduct for anything larger than +/- 5V. This is not dependent on Zener voltage, but because the rail voltage actually turns on the FETs.

Comment: Heating elements rated for 48² / 3 = 768 W can probably take excessive amounts of abuse and survive any surge. I also believe that you dont need to protect your secondary side from voltage spikes, because the heating element will protect the transformer from overvoltage.

Comment: Whoops yes I made as mistake when copying from LTSpice to SE, sorry. Its corrected. The heating element is massive, Im not losing sleep over this one. The SMPS DC-DC on the other hand isnt as resilient. Anyway the condition I need to protect against is disconnect of the heater itself, not switching off on the primary side which would be much less critical I suppose...

Comment: In your comment (nr. 5) you write "from the 24VAC line" while in the problem description you mention a 48 V circuit.

Comment: You'll have to design the circuit such that the MOSFET's anti-parallel diodes don't burn out  before the fuse does AND (obviously, but still a design consideration) the fuse has to be able to handle the heater current.